# CSS - Define Print Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css

If I wanted to create a text editor and wanted to control / display exactly what part of you document will be printed where on a DIN-A4 page, how would that be possible in CSS / JS? How can I know where the page would end and how could I display that in the browser?

[image]

If the grey boxes were my text content, how could I know / show / control where the lines would break (width) and where the page would break (height)?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the specifics for DIN-A4 formatting (width, height, dpi, etc.) and then use those units in your CSS. You can use units like `mm`, `cm`, and `in` to match

Comment: Thanks, this seems to go in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use **CSS Grid** to build up your layout/template.

A good tutorial to walk you through: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Comment: Can you elaborate how CSS Grid would help here?

Comment: You've asked how to control where lines break (basically by defining how your information is displayed on the page) - you can do that using css grid. As long as that's built using those rules then the information will be printed following that layout.